# How to run my own Windows program with wine on Linux?

Tags: linux, wine, .net

I have a program written in C# with .NetFramework and would like to know what I would have to do to get it to run with Wine on a Linux system (if that's possible at all).

Is it as simple as copying the compilation output from Visual Studio into a folder and then pointing Wine to the .exe? Or do I have to alter the program in some way?

Comment: You have to provide the exe file and all dlls used.

Comment: Please click [edit] and provide requested info. Please do not click Add Comment; use [edit] instead because there's no formatting in comments whereas two spaces and an Enter keystroke starts a new line in the Question Editor.